# Check for an item in an Array and then edit this item

Tags: arraylist, drools

I have an array that checks all "OpExs" these will all be in a format such as follows.

```
<opex code = "##">
<nettAmount></nettAmount>
<grossAmount></grossAmount>
<accessibility></accessibility>
</opex>
```

There could be 50 of these, So i want to take a specific one (lets say "MA") and set its Amounts etc, i have the following but i only know how to create a new opex and set its values.
I have no idea how i would go about changing the values of an existing opex. (i have used a boolean as i cannot edit items whilst an array is accessing them.

```
rule "Testing"
salience 500
when
    $result : Result($opexs : optionalExtras)
    Policy($rType : rtpType)
then
        boolean opexThere = false;
        for (OptionalExtra oe : (ArrayList<OptionalExtra>) $opexs){
        logger.info("Array created – Size = ["+$opexs.size()+"]");
            if (oe.getCode().equals("MA"))
            {
                boolean opexThere = true;
            }
            if (opexThere){
            #OptionalExtra opex = new OptionalExtra();
            logger.info("OpEx MA exists original net/gross = ["+oe.getCode()+"-/-"+oe.getNettAmount()+"-/-"+oe.getGrossAmount());
                opex.setNettAmount(1000);
                opex.setGrossAmount(1000);
                opex.setAccessibility("C");
                $result.addOptionalExtra(opex);
                $result.setOpexFlexed(true);
            }               
        }
end
```

If i was to remove the # and include a opex.setCode("MA");
this would simply create a second MA opex, which is not what i wish to do. I need to edit the existing Opex.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i have tried various techniques i would usually use for this but cannot seem to get anything to work.

Comment: This code is not standard Java. If you're using a language built on top of Java (or something altogether different), please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Which language is this? Definitely not java.

Comment: This is just drools, the java-tag can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was way over thinking it, took it back to basics and solved it straight away,

```
rule "modify Opex"
no-loop true
when
    $result : Result($opexList : optionalExtras)
then
       for(OptionalExtra $opex : (ArrayList<OptionalExtra>)$opexList)       {
              if ($opex.getCode().equals("A3")) {
                     $opex.setGrossAmount(1000);
                     logger.info("Amended OPEX " + $opex.getCode());
                     $result.setOpexFlexed(true);
                     $result.setRulesetChanged(true);
              }
       }
end
```

Sorry about the Java/Drools confussion.